# I want to give it the text i wrote in my input tag to and transfer it to another input tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So essentially, every time someone writes on text input tag with placeholder Add new ,a new category/field is formed. And the text they Input should be stored in the field in the order it was entered.

[image]

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Add = () => {
  const [length, setLength] = useState(0);
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [count, setCount] = useState([{ count: 0 }]);
  const [num, setNum] = useState(0);

  const myHashMap = new Map();
  myHashMap.set(num, input);

  const inputHandle = (event) => {
    setInput(event.target.value);
    setNum(...num, num + 1);
    myHashMap(num, input);
  };

  const handle = (event) => {
    if (event.charCode === 13) {
      if (length === 0) {
        setLength(length + 1);
      } else {
        setCount([...count, { count: 0 }]);
      }
    }
  };
  /*  const Remove = (index) => {
              const list = [...count];
              list.splice(index,1);
              setCount(list);
          }
         const helpRemove = (index , e) => {
                const {name,value} = e.target;
            const list = [...count];
            list[index][name] = value;
            setCount(list);
        }
        */
  const InputChange = (e) => {
    setInput(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="bar"
        className="form-control"
        onKeyPress={handle}
        onChange={InputChange}
        placeholder="Add New "
      />
      {count.map((singleService, index) =>
        length !== 0 ? (
          <div key={index} className="input-group mb-3 mt-2">
            <div className="input-group-text">
              <input className="form-check-input mt-0" type="checkbox" />
            </div>
            <input type="text" className="form-control" value={input} />
            <button class="btn btn-outline-danger">X</button>
          </div>
        ) : null
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Add;
```

I tried making it that every time someone writes on input field with Add new placeholder and a new category/field is formed everytime I press enter. And the text I Input should be stored in the field being made in the order it was entered.

The things that worked was making an input field emerge upon pressing enter . But how do i store text in those generated fields?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
If you want to show the input in different fields and empty input on
*"ENTER"* then here is the correct code.

```
import React , {useState} from "react";


    const Add = () => {
const [length ,setLength] = useState(0);
const[input,setInput] = useState("");
const [count , setCount] = useState([]);
const [num , setNum] = useState(0);

const myHashMap = new Map();
myHashMap.set(num,input);



// not used
// const inputHandle = (event) => {

//     setInput(event.target.value);
//     setNum(...num,num+1);
//     myHashMap(num,input);
//         };

    const onKeyPress = (event) => {
            if (event.charCode === 13) {
              // 13 means "ENTER"
              setLength(length+1)

            setCount([...count , input])
            setInput("")
                // if (length === 0) {
                //     setLength(length + 1);
                // } else {
                //     setCount([...count, {count: 0}]);
                // }
            }
        }
        /*  const Remove = (index) => {
              const list = [...count];
              list.splice(index,1);
              setCount(list);
          }
         const helpRemove = (index , e) => {
                const {name,value} = e.target;
            const list = [...count];
            list[index][name] = value;
            setCount(list);
        }
        */
    const InputChange = (e) => {
        setInput(e.target.value);
    }

        return(
    <div>

        <input type="text" id="bar" value={input} className="form-control" onKeyPress ={onKeyPress} onChange = {InputChange} placeholder="Add New "/>
        { count.map((value,index) =>
             length !==0 ? (
                    <div key={index} className="input-group mb-3 mt-2">
                        {/*<div className="input-group-text">
                            <input className="form-check-input mt-0"  type="checkbox"/>
                        </div>*/}
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" value ={value}
                        />
                        <button class = "btn btn-outline-danger">
                            X
                        </button>
                    </div>
                ) : null

        )

        }
    </div>
  );
    }

export default Add;
```

**DEMO**

[image]

Comment: No i meant like how to make a  function of entering a text in a bar and storing into a field by pressing enter.

Like i press some text in the top bar and press enter thena bar is created showing that text.
and the top bar is emptied out by pressing enter.

 in this way multiple input fields are created. And each time the user enter data and saves it in the input field.

Like how To Do list works

Comment: I have edited the code . Check and run. Happy coding..

Comment: Yes it worked. 
Thank you XD
It was StackOverflow policy to not reply so i didn't Lol